# How to interact lavender-commerce/lavender to a exist project

Tags: laravel-5

I have project written by laravel 5.and now,I want install a module e-commerce for it.
So I looked at `lavender-commerce/lavender`.
*Can I bult-in it to my project?

How can i do it?*

Comment: The installation instructions are on the github package of that package. Follow them.

Comment: document say: composer create-project lavender-commerce/lavender.
But i want add it in my project, doesn't init to new project

Comment: you'll have to ask the pacakge author. There is support options listed there.